# Rename photos calculating the age of the person

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to write a script for a file explorer button that allows me, when selecting photos and pressing said button, to rename them with the person's age.

Example: Esther.jpg >>> Esther (1y 3m 8d).jpg

To calculate the age we must use the date of birth of the person, specified in a fixed way in the script; and the date taken of the photo, obtained from the metadata of this.

When executing the following code, an error is generated on line 4, position 5. 'metadata' is null or not an object. Apparently I'm not knowing how to obtain the date taken of the photo.

```js
function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData)
{
    var birthdate = "20210318000000";
    var dateTaken = item.metadata.image.datetaken;
    var diff = dateTaken - birthdate;
    var age = "(" + diff.getFullYear() + "y " + diff.getMonth() + "m " + diff.getDate() + "d)";

    var item = getNewNameData.item;
    var result = item.name_stem + age + item.ext;

    return result;
}
```

Date object
https://www.gpsoft.com.au/help/opus12/index.html#!Documents/Scripting/Date.htm

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @mykaf Error at line 1, position 5. 'metadata' is null or not an object

Comment: You haven't defined `item` yet.

Comment: Other than the `undefined` problem you have other issues. You need to create `Date` objects, since you cannot substract strings from each other. For that to be accurate you need to know the timezone of that `birthdate`. If you pass a properly formated string to the `Date` constructor the current local time zone (of your system/ browser) will be assumed which might be wrong. JavaScript date/ time API is a pain to work with unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't understand very well, because I don't know much about programming, but you are helping me to continue researching and perfecting the code

Comment: You might try starting with the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Ok, I'll study more on the subject, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a check on the metadata that it exists before you do anything like so:

```
function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData) {
    const birthdate = new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00");

    const item = getNewNameData.item;
    const metadata = item.metadata;

    if (metadata && metadata.image && metadata.image.datetaken) {
        const dateTaken = new Date(metadata.image.datetaken);

        const ageDiff = dateTaken - birthdate;
        const years = Math.floor(ageDiff / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const months = Math.floor((ageDiff % (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (30.44 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const days = Math.floor((ageDiff % (30.44 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

        const age = `(${years}y ${months}m ${days}d)`;

        return `${item.name_stem} ${age}${item.ext}`;
    } else {
        return item.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, the result was the following: Esther.jpg > Esther (NaNy NaNm NaNd).jpg

Comment: Although the expected result was not obtained, I am very happy because the script ran well, without generating an error, the perfect result is almost visible.

Comment: I have updated the answer and I guess it should work as expected now.. you can re-try it

Comment: I updated the code, but the result is still the same, it assigns the same value as year, month and day values: NaN

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Mostafa, I think the error is in the format of the dates, could you give the same format to both dates? Thank you so much

Comment: sure, try the updated code now

Comment: Yes, several times

Comment: try it now .. i edited the code so both have same date format

Comment: Now it generates error on line 2

Comment: const birthdate = new Date("2021-03-18T00:00:00");

Comment: When you have time try to read the link that I placed at the end of the question. It is a page of the file explorer itself, maybe the solution is there